# Flutter: keep widget alive (streambuilder)

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app with a Pageview (and at the bottom a cupertinotabbar). Everything 'works'. But when I switch pages, the streambuilders 'glitch'. (There's one on the first page and on the second page) (see video).

I think the problem is that flutter 'destroys' the streambuilders and then reloads them.

I tried putting keepClientAlive on the statefull widget, but didn't work.
Is there a possibility to keep the streambuilder alive?

This is my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: PageView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Discover(currentUser: currentUser),
            Friends(currentUser: currentUser),
            Find(),
          ],
          controller: pageController,
          onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          currentIndex: pageIndex,
          onTap: onTap,
          activeColor: Colors.green,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.search)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.users)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.biking)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

My streambuilder class

```
class BookList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
          default:
            return new ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(document['title']),
                  subtitle: new Text(document['author']),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2yKhqvkT_A&feature=youtu.be

Thanks!